# WebGL drawPixels?

Tags: webgl, gldrawpixels

I have an array of pixels from a gl.readPixels() call. Can I put those pixels back to the drawing buffer or a framebuffer? i.e. I'd like to call something like gl.drawPixels, but there is none in the WebGL API. Am I to use a texture and render it flat, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this short thread: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/168346-Best-Substitute-for-glDrawPixels-Under-OpenGL-ES

> What the Gold Book is telling you is correct. The fastest way to
>   upload textures is to write to a texture bound to an FBO. But what you
>   need to do is generate your pixels as geometry (optimised as much as
>   possible) and then draw them to the FBO using an Orth matrix,
>   GL_POINTS and glDrawArrays.

The optimal solution (WebGL is a branch of GL-ES) is a bit odd, but makes some sense becuase in a browser you don't want people messing with memory directly. Let the app and driver sort it out, at the expense of some voodoo-like constructions in the GL code.

Comment: What does an orth matrix have to do with it? You don't need any matrices in WebGL

Comment: just quoting. Your vertex shader can be matrix-free if you like.